# Jahia error when posting custom form

Tags: forms, jahia

I've created a form with the Jahia Form Builder, but I get this error when posting my form in Live Mode:

```
Error: org.jahia.services.usermanager.JahiaUserManagerService.lookupUser(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jahia/services/usermanager/JahiaUser;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jahia.services.usermanager.JahiaUserManagerService.lookupUser(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jahia/services/usermanager/JahiaUser;
```

I'm using Digital Factory Community 7.1 and module Jahia Form Builder 2.0.5

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Freedomn,

this is actually a bug in the current Jahia Forum and can inly be fixed by using a patched version. See this pull request : https://github.com/Jahia/formbuilder/pull/1